# How to read external identity from the temporary cookie in .net core 2

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

```
[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            // read external identity from the temporary cookie
            var info = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
            var tempUser = info?.Principal;
            if (tempUser == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }

            // retrieve claims of the external user
            var claims = tempUser.Claims.ToList();
```

This is the snippet of external login callback using IdentityServer4. I have migrated to `.net core 1 to 2` and i am getting warning  `HttpContext.Authentication' is obsolete: 'This is obsolete and will be removed in a future version.` So, which method is introduce in .net core 2 to get the identity?

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated quickstarts UI:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/dev

Comment: when i am trying Windows authentication after migrated to .netcore 2.0 . i am getting this exception "InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Negotiate". How can i resolved this?

Comment: It is now called `Windows`.

Comment: I have put [Authorize] attribute in my mvc application and it's give this error InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Comment: even i have add the middleware like this services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Authority = "";
            options.Audience = "";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });    in .net core2.0

Comment: any clue for above problem? @leastprivilege